# Only "audio button" and "play button" on html5 video

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I created my `html5` video section, but i'm using it to display video-ads before every video on my page.

The problem is that i want to show the video with only a big play button and the audio button, without the autostart (so the video can be played on every devices).

How to modify it?

My Code:

```
<video id="advvideo" controls  width="100%" height="auto">
    <source src="images/videos/promo.mp4"  type="video/mp4" >
    <source src="images/videos/promo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    video not supported
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't control `controls` attribute of **html5** `<video>` tag to change play button style.

For big play button you can upload your ad in youtube and use that youtube video with `object` or `embed` or `iframe` tag.

I prefer `<iframe>` tag.

Ex:

```
<iframe  width="425" height="344" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```